# Deprecation of the Marker Class - Google Map API warning

Tags: typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing an app with google maps typescript api, today I get this warn message when the app was launched ->

> Starting February 21, 2024, google.maps.Marker will no longer be
> available. Instead, use google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement. Find
> more information about the discontinuation at
> https://developers.google.com/maps/deprecations.

but AdvancedMarkerElement has no all the properties that has Marker Class...
why is that? I updated @types/google.maps to lastest version and I keep getting the same warn anybody know somethign about it? and how to solve it?

Comment: You'll have to adjust your code to use AdvancedMarkerElement. The properties may not match exactly, but I'd imagine there are ways to have the same functionality. We can help with specific problems you run into, but the answer to your general question is "do what the message tells you to".

Comment: I'm not the only who get into issues implementing this new Class... https://discord.com/channels/676948200904589322/898688881187225630/1210261005674749952

Comment: I read *At this time, `google.maps.Marker` is not scheduled to be discontinued* and *At least 12 months notice will be given before support is discontinued* so where's the problem? And if there's anything you don't know how to do with advanced markers then ask an on-topic question.

Comment: This has been raised also in Public Issue Tracker. You can check it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/326278120).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This deprecation warning has nothing to do with `@types/google.maps` – it's a warning that originates in the Google Maps' [libraries you load](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api).

See, Google Maps is [*versioned*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions). You can explicitly request a *version* through the [optional loading parameter `v`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api). If you don't pass one, Google will default to the `weekly` version – which is where the [deprecation warning likely comes from](https://developers.google.com/maps/deprecations#googlemapsmarker_in_the_deprecated_as_of_february_2023).

Quick "fix" to get rid of this warning: downgrade to the closest [`minor`](https://semver.org/) version, namely `3.55`.

Long-term fix: evaluate *if* and how you can/should migrate your `Markers` to `AdvancedMarkers`. Remember, `Markers` are being deprecated, not *discontinued* – meaning you can essentially continue using them indefinitely for some (legacy) use cases like 3rd party marker clustering etc. Refer to my [Marker Comparison Guide](https://spatialized.io/advanced-google-maps-markers-definitive-guide-94c5a070615e436ab0a255b9f5100a88) or my [Marker Customization Guide](https://gmapsbook.com/learn-google-maps/custom-marker-labels-d15ef7f5e22b4968b106e5cee407b37b) if you need to brush up on these concepts.

Lastly, as @ceejayoz suggests in the comments, `AdvancedMarkers` are essentially a superset of `Markers`: they extend their functionality and improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

### "Hello World" Comparison:

#### Marker (Legacy)

> google.maps.Marker is deprecated (February 21st, 2024 (v3.56)).

**Docs:** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

```
// Initialize and add the map
let map;

function initMap() {
  const myLatLng = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    disableDefaultUI: true, // a way to quickly hide all controls
  });

  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map,
  });
}

initMap();
```

#### AdvancedMarkerElement (new)

**DOCS:** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/overview

Extra step for `AdvancedMarkerElement` is to [Create a map ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/start#create_a_map_id).

```
// Initialize and add the map
let map;

async function initMap_AdvancedMarkerElement() {
  const myLatLng = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

  // The map, centered at Uluru
  map = new Map(document.getElementById("AdvancedMarker_MAP"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
    disableDefaultUI: true, // a way to quickly hide all controls
    mapId: "DEMO_MAP_ID",
  });

  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map: map,
    position: myLatLng,
    title: "Uluru",
  });
}

initMap_AdvancedMarkerElement();
```

Related: [asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing)

**IMPORTANT** - A lot of code ideas (Like changing marker icon, marker styles and so on) - completely changed VS Legacy (Follow the docs).

##### PRE step:

1. In both cases you should **Get an API key and enable the Maps JavaScript API**.
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
2. And of course to load the API script (with your api key)

```
<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?your-key=&loading=async&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

More ways to Load the Maps JavaScript API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api

3. Add Height to map div `#map {height: 400px;}`

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is using Vue one of the most tricky things that I get to make it work is that google maps is not accepting `reactive` or `ref` map object, so when you declare the instance of the map use `shallowRef`. This way the map will accept the AdvanceMarker library as the documentation say.