# Google Maps Marker Deprecation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps

Since 21 February 2024, Google Maps Marker is deprecated, and Google recommends to use AdvancedMarkerElement. However, currently, the AdvancedMarkerElement does not have a feature that i need, and a lot of features are still in beta. Is it okay if I'm not migrating to AdvancedMarker?

i tried to change the marker to AdvancedMarker and set the marker clickable, but i need to change the google maps version to alpha, and its working but i can not use the alpha version for production use because its not stable and it gives a beta banner above the map.

Comment: Review -> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78042237/deprecation-of-the-marker-class-google-map-api-warning?noredirect=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78042237/deprecation-of-the-marker-class-google-map-api-warning?noredirect=1)